# Detecting missing components using Opencv and Python

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

So I have now a running code to detect each components by using template matching, I just used the code that the author has provided in this link (https://www.sicara.fr/blog-technique/object-detection-template-matching).

This code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_MATCHING_THRESHOLD = 0.9

class Template:
    """
    A class defining a template
    """

def __init__(self, image_path, label, color, matching_threshold=DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_MATCHING_THRESHOLD):
    """
    Args:
        image_path (str): path of the template image path
        label (str): the label corresponding to the template
        color (List[int]): the color associated with the label (to plot detections)
        matching_threshold (float): the minimum similarity score to consider an object is detected by template
            matching
    """
    self.image_path = image_path
    self.label = label
    self.color = color
    self.template = cv2.imread(image_path)
    self.template_height, self.template_width = self.template.shape[:2]
    self.matching_threshold = matching_threshold

image = cv2.imread("PCB_reference.jpg")

templates = [
    Template(image_path="T1.png", label="1", color=(0, 0, 255), matching_threshold=0.88),
    Template(image_path="T2.jpg", label="2", color=(0, 255, 0,), matching_threshold=0.8),
    Template(image_path="T3.png", label="3", color=(255, 0, 0,), matching_threshold=0.85),
    Template(image_path="T4.png", label="4", color=(0, 180, 200,), matching_threshold=0.81),
    Template(image_path="T5.png", label="5", color=(110, 180, 200,), matching_threshold=0.91),
    Template(image_path="T6.png", label="6", color=(150, 100, 150,), matching_threshold=0.83),
    Template(image_path="T7.png", label="7", color=(0, 100, 150,), matching_threshold=0.84),
    Template(image_path="T8.png", label="8", color=(110, 100, 200,), matching_threshold=0.96),
 ]

detections = []
for template in templates:
    template_matching = cv2.matchTemplate(template.template, image, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    match_locations = np.where(template_matching >= template.matching_threshold)

for (x, y) in zip(match_locations[1], match_locations[0]):
    match = {
        "TOP_LEFT_X": x,
        "TOP_LEFT_Y": y,
        "BOTTOM_RIGHT_X": x + template.template_width,
        "BOTTOM_RIGHT_Y": y + template.template_height,
        "MATCH_VALUE": template_matching[y, x],
        "LABEL": template.label,
        "COLOR": template.color
    }
    detections.append(match)

def compute_iou(boxA, boxB):
    xA = max(boxA["TOP_LEFT_X"], boxB["TOP_LEFT_X"])
    yA = max(boxA["TOP_LEFT_Y"], boxB["TOP_LEFT_Y"])
    xB = min(boxA["BOTTOM_RIGHT_X"], boxB["BOTTOM_RIGHT_X"])
    yB = min(boxA["BOTTOM_RIGHT_Y"], boxB["BOTTOM_RIGHT_Y"])
    interArea = max(0, xB - xA + 1) * max(0, yB - yA + 1)
    boxAArea = (boxA["BOTTOM_RIGHT_X"] - boxA["TOP_LEFT_X"] + 1) * (boxA["BOTTOM_RIGHT_Y"] - boxA["TOP_LEFT_Y"] + 1)
    boxBArea = (boxB["BOTTOM_RIGHT_X"] - boxB["TOP_LEFT_X"] + 1) * (boxB["BOTTOM_RIGHT_Y"] - boxB["TOP_LEFT_Y"] + 1)
    iou = interArea / float(boxAArea + boxBArea - interArea)
    return iou

def non_max_suppression(objects, non_max_suppression_threshold=0.5, score_key="MATCH_VALUE"):
    """
    Filter objects overlapping with IoU over threshold by keeping only the one with maximum score.
    Args:
        objects (List[dict]): a list of objects dictionaries, with:
            {score_key} (float): the object score
            {top_left_x} (float): the top-left x-axis coordinate of the object bounding box
            {top_left_y} (float): the top-left y-axis coordinate of the object bounding box
            {bottom_right_x} (float): the bottom-right x-axis coordinate of the object bounding box
            {bottom_right_y} (float): the bottom-right y-axis coordinate of the object bounding box
        non_max_suppression_threshold (float): the minimum IoU value used to filter overlapping boxes when
            conducting non-max suppression.
        score_key (str): score key in objects dicts
    Returns:
        List[dict]: the filtered list of dictionaries.
    """
    sorted_objects = sorted(objects, key=lambda obj: obj[score_key], reverse=True)
    filtered_objects = []
    for object_ in sorted_objects:
        overlap_found = False
        for filtered_object in filtered_objects:
            iou = compute_iou(object_, filtered_object)
            if iou > non_max_suppression_threshold:
                overlap_found = True
                break
        if not overlap_found:
            filtered_objects.append(object_)
    return filtered_objects

NMS_THRESHOLD = 0.2
detections = non_max_suppression(detections, non_max_suppression_threshold=NMS_THRESHOLD)

image_with_detections = image.copy()
for detection in detections:
    cv2.rectangle(
        image_with_detections,
        (detection["TOP_LEFT_X"], detection["TOP_LEFT_Y"]),
        (detection["BOTTOM_RIGHT_X"], detection["BOTTOM_RIGHT_Y"]),
        detection["COLOR"],
        2,)

cv2.imshow("res", image_with_detections)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is now my output where it detects the 8 components that I have as a template:

[Current code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcP96.jpg)

I wanted to make an algorithm where I could detect a missing component. For example, supposedly there are four (4) A3 resistors in the reference image but what if my input reading (real-time camera feed) has only three A3 resistors the same goes to the missing one resistor (3220). I wanted to ask what is the best approach/method to use to make this work.

Example this is my desired output:

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlOKP.jpg)

Should I save the position of each template where they are supposed to be placed and make a database containing the template and their specific location? This is to tell that in this location (e.g x= 20. y = 50) a resistor should be present. I am thinking of having csv file but I don't think it's possible or efficient to store the templates image directory and also the position of each template.

I have read that SSIM could be use for the missing components detection and there are also some that uses deep-learning like YOLO for neural networks but I think that is too complex for me to begin with.

Comment: If you have a csv file of the locations, then why would you need to do template matching?  P.S. your desired output has no resistors marked. It looks like an input image.

Comment: If your have multiple circuit boards and the circuit boards are supposed to be identical, except for a few missing component, then perhaps do SIFT or ORB and warp one to match the other, then get the difference to see what has changed.

Comment: I am planning to make csv file for locations instead, because if I solely do template matching, I don't have idea on what approach or method to tell if there is a missing component.

And with the desired output, I purposely put the input image having missing resistor to indicate that I wanted my output to detect the missing components ideally.

Comment: @fmw42 yes I do have identical circuit boards and trying to create a program that could detect possible missing components. Will do study and read articles on SIFT and ORB, thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: `@yessi`, see https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html

Comment: Thanks, I've read the articles already but I deem its concept as complex as key points are the matched ones, while what I wanted was to see the difference and I am yet to look for the way to get the difference if ever I tried ORB because SIFT is patented and I can't be able to use it.

Comment: @fmw42 I'm thinking of trying the approach of locating the locations of each components, do you think it is efficient to store their location in a library to be able to tell if ever a component is missing? 

Like if at coordinates(20,50) where resistor_A should be located is not found on the input image, then is it possible to tell that because during the matching, at coordinates x=20, y=50 nothing is detected during the match, then it can be considered as missing component. I'm not sure if this is a good alternative.

Comment: That might be OK. But you need to allow some tolerances